# How do I match the sibling height when parent height is exceeded

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with a fixed height.

Inside, two divs displayed inline (next to each other)
Both divs have a variable height.
When one of the divs height exceeds the parent height (Overflow is set to scroll), I need both siblings to have the same height.

height: 100% doesn't work.

Here is a more clear example:

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHnxv.png)

Comment: Do you need to use only CSS or is a bit of JavaScript okay?

Comment: @Riccardo Chimisso, why do you want to sue JS for such simpel thing? Either a table or a grid with auto-height will work just fine and no need to run JS for it. Dont make stuff more complicated then it actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#parent {  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#childOne {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

#childTwo {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="childOne">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="childTwo">
    <p>Different Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

use a grid to do that with an auto height, then the columns will be the same height and adjust to the largest content. Alternativly you could use a table but I recommend against this ancient technique for full responsivness.

Answer (score 0):

When you set overflow:scroll you tell the browser to constrain your container in height and scroll for it this way you have to set the maximum height to the element, after which there will be scrolling

If you do not limit the height, then there will be no scrolling, so what's your logic?

You need to constrain then the height of both elements, you are doing something wrong

I offer you my example without scrolling:

https://jsfiddle.net/a2nurvpg/2/

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda illum, laborum alias aspernatur quis? Quasi laboriosam tenetur delectus sed quaerat dicta, hic eum magnam impedit ex? Atque dolorem sequi inventserunt quam llam quaerat corporis impedit veritatis? Corrupti nobis deleniti ipsa nostrum, tempora dolor velit. Similique minus vero quibusdam mollitia deleniti nobis modi doloribus.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="box">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt nam optio eveniet adipisci reiciendis, sed facere tenetur. Reprehenderit fugiat expedita aliquam illum perferendis sit nesciunt maxime sapiente tempore. Ipsa architecto pariatur delectus enim sint aliquam perferendis corrupti animi impedit blanditiis explicabo ex, quam sunt in quibusdam! Nobis iusto voluptate nesciunt placeat sint, ut molestiae repellat facilis. Aliquid consequatur cumque natus ipsa officiis est, itaque quisquam quod, eius architecto cum qui saepe iure nisi sit perspiciatis! Ipsam, facere voluptate quisquam sapiente. Aliquid accusantium voluptate tempora quas, accusamus? Odio, amet adipisci cum impedit in modi soluta ullam quae expedita praesentium dignissimos suscipit doloribus inventore perferendis, necessitatibus obcaecati laborum voluptates repudiandae quas at eos. Molestias similique reiciendis possimus voluptatem neque dolores cupiditate aliquam rerum repellendus eligendi. Iure a in deleniti aliquid aperiam, quod necessitatibus assumenda quis, maxime velit similique tempora. Omnis nulla, asperiores suscipit laborum praesentium aperiam temporibus consequatur veniam quod vel porro repellendus voluptate, at dolor harum consequuntur beatae obcaecati ea magni quis nemo quisquam illum placeat ipsam! Ducimus tempora explicabo perferendis ex cum impedit labore voluptatibus accusantium et, eos illo, consequatur minima aspernatur at error recusandae unde cupiditate libero corporis est officia harum obcaecati. Eos, odio, nulla. Recusandae facilis ex impedit debitis odit ea nemo at excepturi quibusdam blanditiis expedita maxime dolores, molestias vel consectetur repellat doloremque, laudantium asperiores, cumque in porro aspernatur id culpa exercitationem enim. Ipsum, nobis sint qui harum quos autem ullam nemo veniam labore vel dolores placeat tempora, modi est nihil vitae consectetur minima, ab beatae nesciunt commodi tempore? Esse ducimus repellat dicta mollitia quae quibusdam doloremque nihil iusto sapiente provident facilis accusamus totam repellendus, suscipit eaque incidunt omnis unde, voluptatem, quia tempore praesentium consectetur sequi. Voluptatem quisquam, accusamus repellendus fuga unde, saepe optio corporis molestiae recusandae vero magni ipsam perferendis laborum ullam eos sunt commodi repellat!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.cell {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box {
  background-color: #CCC;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100%
}
```

In addition, today I answered one question that uses the  [JS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63528418/html-side-by-side-paragraphs/63528748#63528748) for dynamic elements

Comment: intrestign approach to solve the problem but imho way to complicated for such simple matter. you need more div boxes then necessary when you actually could do it with 3.

Comment: I did it for beauty only to show the gaps, you can remove .box elements and it will work